# iis url redirect http to non www https

Tags: redirect, iis

i need to redirect from

[www.domain.de](http://www.domain.de) to https://domain.de
-works

http://www.domain.de to https://domain.de
-works

http://domain.de to https://domain.de
-does not work

```
rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: i assume that rewrite is properly inside its opening tags, even though here in code the opening chevron is missing. and can you elaborate "Imported Rule 1" ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this will work for you, the search pattern has the optional www and redirects using the back reference C:2, the rule has a condition to only run against non https.

This is the pattern:

```
"^(www\.)?(.*)$"
```

where:

```
{C:0} - www.domain.de
{C:1} - www.
{C:2} - domain.de
```

Here's the rule in full:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: Where is the role could be placed? in web.config file on the root?

Comment: @David Martin, what about {https}://www.domain.com to {https}://domain.com

Comment: @RohitArora I'm not sure I fully understand your issue, can I suggest you post a new question?

Comment: @DavidMartin In short its not working for me. I also want the same for IIS 8. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you want the redirect to stay on the same page (keep the path info) instead of going to the website root, change the action into: `<action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer doesn't handle the special case `https://www.domain.de`.

These rules do the complete job:

```xml
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS without www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Special case for HTTPS with www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect www to non www:

1. Add DNS entry for www.yourdomain.com to refer to your server's public IP
2. Then you need to Edit Bindings of your website and "Add Binding" www.yourdomain.com
3. Add a rewrite rule to your website using iis:

> ```
> <rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
>   <match url="*" />
>   <conditions>
>     <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
>   </conditions>
>   <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
> </rule>
> ```

Reference: http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain

Answer (score 2):

If you want something more flexible than for your three examples, change your HTTP_HOST pattern to : `\w+\.\w+$`.  That would work for all three examples plus anything else, like *subdomain.abcdef.domain.de*.

If you use this regex either encase it in parenthesis or change C:1 to C:0 in your action.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
    <rule name="NameRule1" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true" >
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

I got it from: https://medium.com/iis-and-windows-server/redirect-url-from-www-to-non-www-in-iis7-5-4d2909b9704

Comment: This is incorrect, as the question talks about HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many of solutions but below works for me:

1. Right click on Domain and Add a Site bindings, add one more domain with www:

[image]

2. Restart services. it should work.

Comment: 1. Changing bindings does not require service restart. 2. You haven't tried enough.

Answer (score -1):

These rewrite rules matches the following URL's:

- www.example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com

They will all redirect to: https://example.com

These rewrite rules may redirect twice because of the separate rules. (I'm a newbie with regex)

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WWW" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com{PATH_INFO}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```