# URL Rewrite and Web.config

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting

i need to redirect from

`www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com`
`http://www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com`
`http://domain.com` to `https://domain.com`
I have the following lines of code and it works fine

```
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />

        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

i take it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110411/iis-url-redirect-http-to-non-www-https)
I want also rediredt from
`https://www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com`
i add the following lines

```
 <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^https://www.(.*)" />

        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:1}"  />
      </rule>
```

but it no redirect from `https://www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com

why?

Answer (score 0):

You are the `conditions` snippet in between your `<match>` and `<action>` tags for https redirection.

Try this:

```
 <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://www.domain\.com$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:1}"  />
 </rule>
```