# URL Canonization Isuue, without www my website not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, iis, web

I have a website with http://www.example.com and I was not able to access it when i enter my domain as http://example.com.

Is there any modification done on my codeigniter files or it has to changed from server?

If it is from server please provide me an solution.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try to access your website as http://example.com? You get an error? Is it redirecting to www?

First of all I would check the DNS configuration just to be sure that both example.com and www.example.com point to the same ip address.

Then if you use apache you could redirect the www version of your website to the non-www version using rewrite rules in .htaccess

If you use nginx you have to add these rewrite rules in the nginx config for that vhost.

I think you need to provide more details about your actual configuration, what have tried by now and so on in order to get help.

UPDATE: For IIS configuration I think you should check this link:
[iis url redirect http to non www https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110411/iis-url-redirect-http-to-non-www-https)

Comment: yes i get an error "Server not found.

Comment: Could you provide your actual nginx vhost configuration for www.example.com?

Comment: It hosted on IIS web server

Comment: @LoadingMinds if your app runs on IIS web server why did you tagged for apache and not IIS?

Comment: @Eineki thanks bro i will update.